# Google Search Ranking and Switching to HTTPS

Tags: seo, google-search-console, dns, https

We have switched to an HTTPS site to replace the client's old site. The domain name is the same, but the majority of pages have different names and different URLs compared to the old site. Redirects are used where required to ensure users are getting the https pages.

I have not been successful in verifying the domain property in Google Search Console. Even after waiting more than 72 hours, the required DNS TXT record is not available. Using Dig, all I can see is the spf TXT record.

I'm looking at the alternative of adding another property with the https prefix instead of using a domain property. My two main questions are:

1. How long should I wait before I delete the previous property for the http version?
2. What will be the search ranking impact, in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can only see the SPF TXT record using dig, that tells me that something is wrong - you should be able to see the Google verification TXT record too. This suggests that either the Google TXT record was not properly set up on your nameserver provider, or that maybe it was set up on the wrong subdomain.

The good news is that whether or not your domain is verified in Search Console has no bearing on your search ranking impact, so you can take as long as you need to to get the verification figured out.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out there is a configuration issue with the hosting company's name servers.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend upon Google how quickly they will index and verify your website, but normally they will take 24 hrs to verify and index websites.

While you get a boost in ranking as stated by Google [here](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html), sometimes it works as a tiebreaker in the search results in Google.